# Is there an algorithm to determine if an image is a fractal?

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, geometry

I am studying cellular automata and some of them apparently produce images that look like fractals and some don't. It's not completely clear to me what a fractal is, because I think it's possible to take any picture and make it into animation that deceives the viewer by zooming in and drawing something self similar.

So, my questions are:

1) how can I tell a fractal from non-fractal, for example, why does rule 0 not produce a fractal, say, I start with one pixel and keep zooming in on a corner of it and it will look like a corner of a square and I can do it for an indefinite amount of time, is that not a fractal?

2) What is a good algorithm to determine if a picture produced by CA is a fractal? (Maybe I need to look at proportions of cell colors at different scale or something like that?).

My thoughts on the algorithm:
We can view the the picture as a 2 dimensional grid, each row is a string. Let's create a suffix tree and insert all substrings of each row and then see if there are a lot of repetitions of certain long enough string of length N. Is that a good way?

Thanks.

Comment: As for question 1. If you simply zoom in on a single pixel, there's no need for using a cellular automaton. In addition rule 0 won't produce any output anyways. A fractal must always be self-similar, which means it basically consists of smaller copies of itself (sry for that ugly description, but it should do here). A black square doesn't consist of smaller copies of itself, it's just a back square.

Comment: @Paul, thanks. What do you think of my algorithm? Is it right or wrong?

Comment: That'll result in a horrendously large trie. Even for a relatively small grid the effort would stack up to a pretty large scale. And fractals will usually fill a few rows with their pattern (e.g. rule 126). Since cellular automata can only generate patterns of a triangle-form due to their generation-form the simplest solution would be to detect triangles in the pattern that is produced by a CA

Comment: @Paul, yes, I agree, but as I mention we will only insert long enough sequences into the trie and not waste any space with sequences of length smaller than 10, for example. Also, I usually use 500x500 grid for my cellular automata, so I don't think it will be that bad. I can use patricia tries to save space, also if the behavior is highly regular and recurrent there shouldn't be too many strings there.

Comment: well, the trie isn't that much of a problem (sry, forgot to remove that from my comment). The main-problem is indeed the number of substrings. For a string of length 500 even eliminating all substrings up to a length of 10 will still leave you with a number of substrings that is way too large. The processing-time would simply be too large. You can try that approach, but I doubt you'll get enough speed out of your computer to make that work within acceptable time.

Comment: @Paul I understand that. However, that's the only way I can think of to determine recurrent behavior, is it not? As for fractal behavior, you suggest detecting triangles,  here, since we gotta check the triangles of many possible sizes and iterate over the entire grid for each possible size, it will also take a pretty long time.

Comment: @Paul I am only saying that because I once wrote a program to detect coins and it was also taking a very long time..

Comment: actually searching for triangles won't take **that** long. These triangles have some simple properties that make detection pretty simple. They are isosceles and have at least one side that is aligned to an axis of the grid. Finding the side that is aligned to an axis of the grid is pretty trivial and finding the other sides based on that line isn't that hard either. Should be doable in atmost `O(n ^ 2)` for a grid of size `n x n`, which is a lot better than checking all substrings of a string of length n.

Comment: @Paul, yea, I know that there are only 3 kinds of triangles there, I have already studied that. But do you know a better way,  than what I suggested, to detect specifically recurrent behavior, that is not necessarily fractal?

Comment: yes, I do know such algorithms. But there's a bit of a problem: the issue is not detecting any recurrent behavior, but **non-trivial** recurrences. E.g. the pattern "01" will appear quite often in your grid, but it's trivial and useless to detect that recurrence. And your algorithm will only check for recurrences that can be deducted from single rows, while some of the patterns, like the triangles will cover multiple rows. So the actual problem is an algorithm that finds the specific sort of recurrence you're searching for.

Comment: @Paul, but recurring behavior is not about triangles, it's when you have a string of the form S=AXB, and the substring X produces substring Y on the next row, now imagine that B from S is equal to ZXC, then that same X will also produce a Y, and it will be the same pattern, that's what I mean, and like I said, I can choose the size of things to insert into the trie to be longer than 2, of course.

Comment: If you're searching for **any** row-specific recurrences your approach should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the fastest and most robust approach is to calculate fractal dimension of the image. Consider black-and-white image. We have original large image and we'll compute so called mipmap from it (series of smaller and smaller images). In each of it, we'll compute the total count of black pixels. If we have just a line segment on an image (or some curve), it would roughly double number of pixels when we double the resolution, it corresponds to dimension 1.

If we have some solid (square, circle, ellipse and so on), it would quadruple number of pixels when we double the resolution, so it is dimension 2.

Fractals have, well, fractional dimension, typically from 1 to 2, though values less then 1 also occur (Kantor dust).

Say, we have 1 black pixel on the smallest image (2x2), 3 pixels on 4x4, 
7 pixels on 8x8, 19 pixels on 16x16, 50 pixels on 32x32. If we have some curve, we would expect 16 times (32/2) more pixels on 32x32 then on 2x2.

If we have solid, we would expect 16^2 = 256 times more pixels on 32x32. But we have some intermediate result. We have an equation:

N = Norig * (Wcur / Worig) ^ FracDim,

where 
- N is number of black pixels at current resolution,
- Norig is number of black pixels at original resolution,
- Wcur is current image width,
- Worig is original image width
- FracDim is fractal dimension we want to find. Take a log of both parts:

Log(N) = Log(Norig) + FracDim * Log(Wcur / Worig)

And we have 'experimental data' like pairs (Wcur; N). Find FracDim by rms approach (best fit) and that's all. If it's too far from integer values, than we have fractal on the image.

Surprizingly enough, approach like that was used to determine is the signature on the paper real or faked one. If it was written fast (usual case when it is legit), ink is not absorbed by paper that much, but when someone tries to fake a signature, it is more long process so ink is absorbed a much. The image of ink absorption under large magnification is fractal one. When fine-tuned, it works like a charm.